# Why is there a "ghost" of the sprite stuck in the background? GMS 2

Tags: game-physics, gml, game-maker-studio-2

So I'm making a game in game maker studio 2 and it's kinda like football but with flying. I just made the movement and jetpack controls and last night it was working but when I booted it up this morning, this happened. Normally when you move, you only see one image (the sprite) but it was showing where it had been and leaving the image there. I don't know if it is a RAM error or I did something wrong in the code.

code:
Step event in player object

```
/// @description Movement logic
// Get the input
var x_input = (keyboard_check(vk_right) - keyboard_check(vk_left)) * acceleration_;

// Vector variables
var vector2_x = 0;
var vector2_y = 1;

// Horizontal movement
velocity_[vector2_x] = clamp(velocity_[vector2_x]+x_input, -max_velocity_[vector2_x], max_velocity_[vector2_x]);
var on_ground = tile_collide_at_points(collision_tile_map_id_, [bbox_left, bbox_bottom], [bbox_right-1, bbox_bottom]);
if keyboard_check(vk_right){
    if on_ground {
    sprite_index = spr_player_ground_right
    direction_=0
    }
    else {
    sprite_index = spr_player_flying_right
    direction_=0
    }
}

if keyboard_check(vk_left){
    if on_ground {
    sprite_index = spr_player_ground_left
    direction_=1
    }
    else {
    sprite_index = spr_player_flying_left
    direction_=1
    }
}

// Friction
if x_input == 0 {
    velocity_[vector2_x] = lerp(velocity_[vector2_x], 0, .2);
}


// Gravity
velocity_[vector2_y] += gravity_;

// Move and contact tiles
move_and_contact_tiles(collision_tile_map_id_, 64, velocity_);

// Jumping
var on_ground = tile_collide_at_points(collision_tile_map_id_, [bbox_left, bbox_bottom], [bbox_right-1, bbox_bottom]);
//if on_ground {
    // Jumping
    if keyboard_check(vk_space) {
        velocity_[vector2_y] = -jump_speed_;
        if direction_=0 {
        sprite_index = spr_player_flying_right
        direction_=0
        }
        else {
        sprite_index = spr_player_flying_left
        direction_=1
        }
    }
//}
```

Create Event in player object

```
/// @description Movement variables
velocity_ = [0, 0];
gravity_ = 0.3;
jump_speed_ = 4;
max_velocity_ = [8, 32];
acceleration_ = 2.1;
direction_ = 0;

// Get the tilemap id
var layer_id = layer_get_id("CollisionTiles");
collision_tile_map_id_ = layer_tilemap_get_id(layer_id);
```

I think that code should cover it.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you disabled this check box in the current room that draws the background?
If so just recheck it.

Note this is gm8 but it should be the same.

[image: Check Draw Backgrund]

Comment: I found out that whenever I choose the spr_crowd sprite, it leaves a "ghost". How could I fix this?

Comment: What you have supplied isn't enough for me to help you, i need screen shots at least.

Comment: It was the backgrounds fault, The image wasn't filling the screen so the "ghost" effect happened. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is having this problem i know a fix that work for me.

make a new background layer and place it at the very bottom of all the other layers.

[link to photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfVBt.png)

make sure you are on that new background layer and go into properties Room

[link to photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHpCc.png)

and go to viewports and cameras

[link to photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Hcz.png)

after that make sure you have clear viewport background checked

[link to photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzJnz.png)

if this does not work for you i'm sorry i couldn't help